# Get Count of two columns using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I need to get the count of two fields using NHibernate query. Given the sample data of historicalList below, the result should be 1 Project assign to 2 Nodes. How to get the result using the Nhibernate query. Please see below my approach, Anyone can help to rewrite the code?

```
//Sample Data
var nodelist= new List<Node>{
new Node{1, "Node1"},
new Node{2, "Node2"},
new Node{3, "Node3"},
new Node{4, "Node4"},
new Node{5, "Node5"},
}

var projectlist= new List<Project>{
new Project{1, "Project1"},
new Project{2, "Project2"},
new Project{3, "Project3"},
new Project{4, "Project4"},
new Project{5, "Project5"},
}

var historicalList= new List<Historical>
{
 new Historical{1, 1,1}
 new Historical{1, 1,2}
}



public class Node
    {
        public virtual long ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string NodeName { get; set; }
    }

 public class Project
    {
        public virtual long ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string ProjectName { get; set; }
    }


public Historical
{
        public virtual long ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string ProjectID { get; set; }
        public virtual string NodeID { get; set; }     
}


//sample code 

 using (var session = OpenSession())
            {
                var historical= session.Query<Historical>()
              .Where(
                  x => nodeIds.Contains(x.Node.ID));
                var nodeCount = historical.Select(y => y.Node.ID).Distinct().Count();
                var projectCount = historical.Select(y => y.Project.ID).Distinct().Count();


            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach without using DISTINCT.

```
var historical   = session.Query<Historical>().Where(x => /* other filters here*/ );

var nodeCount    = session.Query<Node>()
                   .Where(n => historical.Any(h => h.NodeId == n.NodeId)).Count();

var projectCount = session.Query<Project>()
                   .Where(p => historical.Any(h => h.ProjectId == p.ProjectId)).Count();
```

To execute the two count in one roundtrip, use [ToFutureValue](http://blog-of-darius.blogspot.com/2013/01/nhiberbnate-fix-added-ability-to-use.html), it's built-in now on latest NHibernate.

```
var historical   = session.Query<Historical>().Where(x => /* other filters here*/ );

var nodeCount    = session.Query<Node>()
                   .Where(n => historical.Any(h => h.NodeId == n.NodeId))
                   .ToFutureValue(f => f.Count());

var projectCount = session.Query<Project>()
                   .Where(p => historical.Any(h => h.ProjectId == p.ProjectId))
                   .Count();
```

Note, you can't see if the two statements is executed one roundtrip through SQL Server profiler, you have to use [NHProf](http://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures). If you can't avail NHProf, just benchmark the query with and without ToFutureValue.

Also, please benchmark the Where+Any approach against Distinct and see if Where+Any is faster, otherwise just use Distinct approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **join** on **Linq to NHibernate API** directly even if you don't have the regular mapping relations to use **QueryOver**.

```
var historical = session.Query<Historical>()
    .Where(x => nodeIds.Contains(x.Node.ID));

var ncv = (from h in historical
           join n in session.Query<Node>() on h.NodeID equals n.ID
           select h).ToFutureValue(x => x.Count());

var pcv = (from h in historical
           join p in session.Query<Project>() on h.ProjectID equals p.ID
           select h).ToFutureValue(x => x.Count()); // Future is not required here

var nodeCount = ncv.Value;
var projectCount = pcv.Value;
```